# Validating large xml files with .Net NMatrix.Schematron

Tags: c#, xml, xml-validation, schematron

I'm using schematron for validating large xml files (several megabytes). Validation is quite fast if files are ok (if there is no errors). But when the error count increases so increases the execution time of the schematron validation time.

Is there any way to stop the schematron XSLT-validation when for example 200 errors are found. That would help because if there are big files which contain hundreds of occurrences of the same error it would certainly be enough to report only first errors and ask the user to validate file again after correcting those.

Need to restrict Schematron validation to certain limit (error count 100 or 500), that will boost application performance. This limit is needed in case of hundreds & millions records are in xml files (more than 100 mb files).

Comment: Can you add a sample of the code, that you are using right now, so we can go from there?

Comment: I am using Assembly NMatrix.Schematron.dll, v0.56.7815.28750 (.NET Framework Library -Schematron) for validating XML files with XSD.

Comment: I am using Assembly NMatrix.Schematron.dll, v0.56.7815.28750 (.NET Framework Library -Schematron) for validating XML files with XSD.                                   
Validator val = new Validator();
val.AddSchema(XSD_File);
XPathDocument doc = (XPathDocument)val.Validate(XmlFilePath);                               
If you see, In this code, only xsd schema added and then schematron's validate method called with xml file. So after giving to schematron, it keep on doing validation for millions of records. Need to stop after certain limit.

Comment: Are you sure you're doing Schematron validation? It looks like you're using a tool that's capable of doing Schematron validation, but you're only using it to do W3C XML Schema (XSD) validation (there are many tools that can do both). Or is it the case that you have Schematron rules embedded in the XSD?

Comment: Creation of object of XPathDocument, with XmlValidatingReader as a parameter. i.e. navdoc = new XPathDocument(r) -> Here constructor has been called to instantiate the object, with the help of XmlReader Object (that is "r" as a parameter & navdoc as object of IXPathNavigable). Now this is code where object created & at the same time, read only validation happened, with reader object contain info about schema & xml. Is there any way we can restrict this validation to certain limit? Because this validation happened with the help of system.xml namespace (.net api) & we can not control over it.

Comment: @user16038825: Please edit the question instead of adding comments.